# Grouped list by startWith

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I want make design like contact , it will show list person and grouped by first letter of name like above image. I create class **Alphabet** to filter name by first letter and class **Person** as list

## Model

```
class Person {
  int id;
  String fullName;
  Person({this.id, this.fullName});
}

List<Person> listPerson = [
  Person(id: 1, fullName: 'Zeffry Reynando'),
  Person(id: 2, fullName: 'Alexander'),
  Person(id: 3, fullName: 'Zulkarnain'),
  Person(id: 4, fullName: 'Zahira'),
  Person(id: 5, fullName: 'Syarif H'),
  Person(id: 6, fullName: 'Helmoy'),
];

class Alphabet {
  int id;
  String name;

  Alphabet({this.id, this.name});
}

List<Alphabet> listAlphabet = [
  Alphabet(id: 1, name: 'a'),
  Alphabet(id: 2, name: 'b'),
  Alphabet(id: 3, name: 'c'),
  Alphabet(id: 4, name: 'd'),
  Alphabet(id: 5, name: 'e'),
  Alphabet(id: 6, name: 'f'),
  Alphabet(id: 7, name: 'g'),
  Alphabet(id: 8, name: 'h'),
  Alphabet(id: 9, name: 'i'),
  Alphabet(id: 10, name: 'j'),
  Alphabet(id: 11, name: 'k'),
  Alphabet(id: 12, name: 'l'),
  Alphabet(id: 13, name: 'm'),
  Alphabet(id: 14, name: 'n'),
  Alphabet(id: 15, name: 'o'),
  Alphabet(id: 16, name: 'p'),
  Alphabet(id: 17, name: 'q'),
  Alphabet(id: 18, name: 'r'),
  Alphabet(id: 19, name: 's'),
  Alphabet(id: 20, name: 't'),
  Alphabet(id: 21, name: 'u'),
  Alphabet(id: 22, name: 'v'),
  Alphabet(id: 23, name: 'w'),
  Alphabet(id: 24, name: 'x'),
  Alphabet(id: 25, name: 'y'),
  Alphabet(id: 26, name: 'z'),
];
```

After that , i create function to return List **Map<String,List **Person**>** key as first letter of name and value as List **Person**.

```
Map<String, List<Person>> grupPerson() {
  Map<String, List<Person>> tempMap = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < listAlphabet.length; i++) {
    final result = listPerson
        .where((person) => person.fullName.toLowerCase().startsWith(listAlphabet[i].name))
        .toList();
    for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
      final original = tempMap[listAlphabet[i].name];
      if (original == null) {
        tempMap[listAlphabet[i].name] = [result[j]];
      } else {
        tempMap[listAlphabet[i].name] = [...original, result[j]];
      }
    }
  }

  return tempMap;
}

/// Result 
{a: [Instance of 'Person'], h: [Instance of 'Person'], s: [Instance of 'Person'], z: [Instance of 'Person', Instance of 'Person', Instance of 'Person']}
```

But i don't know how make design like above using my return Map.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full example of how you can do it:

[image]

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  final list = [
    Person('John'),
    Person('Mark'),
    Person('Jessica'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('Zahira'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('John'),
    Person('Mark'),
    Person('Jessica'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('Zahira'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('John'),
    Person('Mark'),
    Person('Jessica'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('Zahira'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('John'),
    Person('Mark'),
    Person('Jessica'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('Zahira'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('John'),
    Person('Mark'),
    Person('Jessica'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('Zahira'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('John'),
    Person('Mark'),
    Person('Jessica'),
    Person('Alexander'),
    Person('Zahira'),
    Person('Alexander'),
  ];

  final Map<String, List<Person>> groupedLists = {};

  void groupMyList() {
    list.forEach((person) {
      if (groupedLists['${person.name[0]}'] == null) {
        groupedLists['${person.name[0]}'] = <Person>[];
      }

      groupedLists['${person.name[0]}'].add(person);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    groupMyList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          for (var entry in groupedLists.entries)
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 90,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(entry.key),
                  Container(
                    height: 60,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: entry.value.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                          child: Text(entry.value[index].name),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Don't forget to mark it as answered if it's correct, Thank you!

Comment: Better than my logic , nice ! little improve , if list can in order (A , D, Z etc).

Comment: If you want to display the list in alphabetical order, you can initialize the map first by inserting A, B, C, ...,Z in order, this will do the trick because Maps in dart uses LinkedHashMap by default, which will iterate over the maps' key in order.